# Application got/lost focus event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a application that opens some child windows with the parameterless Show()-Methode. So the child-windows have no owner, which enabled them to be behind or in front of the main window.

Now I would like to know if the whole application gets or losts focus. Is there a single event to do this?

I tried OnActivate/OnDeactivate and OnGotFocus/OnLostFocus which only reports events for a single form. This means the OnLostFocus-event is fired when the application lost focus, but also if another form is focused.

Comment: Why don't you just subscribe all windows to their Focus event

Comment: Becaus Lost focus is ambiguous. It could mean that the application lost the focus or that another window got the focus.

Comment: Im pretty sure windows forms have an event that triggers when they get focus. Also if it would get fired when they get it or lose it, I assume .NET would at least have information in the eventargs that tells you whats what. If not, I don't know how to help

Comment: There is a dedicated Windows message for this, WM_ACTIVATEAPP.  It was intentionally not exposed in Winforms since it is a dangerous message, lots of ways to shoot your left foot because the OS window manager keeps an internal lock to prevent re-entrancy problems.  If your program deadlocks then you do too much, using BeginInvoke() is a way to take the sting out of such a deadlock by intentionally delaying the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle [`WM_ACTIVATEAPP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-activateapp) in your main form and get notified about activation or deactivation of your app:

```
private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x1C;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_ACTIVATEAPP)
    {
        if (m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero)
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Text = "Deactivated"; }));
        else
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Text = "Activated"; }));
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

**Note:** As it's already mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835394/application-got-lost-focus-event#comment94521310_53835394) by Hans, when using above option, you should be careful to not fall into a deadlock and infinite loop. Make sure you read the comments.

---

As another option, you also can detect activation or deactivation of every form by handling [`Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activate?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Deactivate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate?view=netframework-4.7.2) event. When a form deactivates, you can check if the app is still foreground, by checking check if `Form.ActiveForm` has value:

```
private void f_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (Form.ActiveForm == null)
            Text = "App Deactivated"; //App deactivated
        else
            Text = "Still Active";   //App is still active
    }));
}
```

Comment: This answer ought to point out the dangers of that message.  I added a comment to the question, consider adopting it and flagging the comment as "no longer needed".